# How to visually compare two revisions of a folder versioned by SVN on Linux?

Tags: linux, svn, diff, meld

I can compare a current folder state to its latest revision using the following command:

```
meld .
```

`meld` shows a list of changed files. One can click on each file and see a diff.

Is it possible to compare a current folder state to its specific revision (not the latest one)?

TortoiseSVN allows to compare arbitrary revisions, however it works on Windows only. SmartSVN is proprietary. SVN CLI is unusable for big changesets (CLI diff is fine for small commits, but it's very hard to use it for branch comparision with a lot of changes).

Maybe I could checkout the revision to compare into a separate folder and compare two folders using `meld`. But I guess there should be a simpler approach.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "SVN CLI is unusable for big changesets."?

Comment: For example, a branch has 50 changed files located in different folders. Some of the files has 1000+ lines. Only few of these lines are changed, but I need to see whole file to understand change context. It's very hard to understand the meaning of changes using a CLI diff only. CLI diff is usable only for small commits. It's unusable for branch comparision and merging.

Comment: svn client shows diffs in context and you don't need to examine whole files. It shows only the changed parts: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/history/#svn.tour.history.diff.reposrepos. If your client shows that whole file is different when only portions of it were changed, then I guess that the file's encoding was changed.

Comment: But I need to examine whole files :) For example it contains 1000 lines and only 1 line is changed. I can't understand the meaning of this change seeing only this line and few prev/next lines. `meld` is ideal for my task, because 1) it shows a list of files 2) shows whole file contents and highlights differences 3) it's not sequential, I can examine files in any order. But it can compare a current state only to a latest revision.

Comment: It seems to me you are asking for [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder comparision is usually required for code review or branch merging. It seems that the simplest approach is as follows:

1. Find last trunk revision merged to a current brach
2. If the current branch was not merged from trunk, then find the branch creation revision
3. Checkout trunk with a specified revision to some folder
4. Compare the trunk folder and the brach folder

I didn't found any existing tools supporting it. Here is a bash script I use, maybe it will be useful for someone:

```
TRUNK_BASE_PATH=~/tmp

BRANCH_RELATIVE_URL=$(svn info --no-newline --show-item relative-url)
if [[ "$BRANCH_RELATIVE_URL" != *"/branches/"* ]]; then
  echo "Run it in a branch. Relative URL should contain /branches/. Given: $BRANCH_RELATIVE_URL"
  exit 1
fi

TRUNK_RELATIVE_URL=${BRANCH_RELATIVE_URL%%/branches/*}/trunk
echo "Trunk relative URL: $TRUNK_RELATIVE_URL"

ROOT_URL=$(svn info --no-newline --show-item repos-root-url)
TRUNK_URL=${ROOT_URL}${TRUNK_RELATIVE_URL:1}
echo "Trunk URL: $TRUNK_URL"

TRUNK_PATH=${TRUNK_BASE_PATH}/${TRUNK_URL#*://}
echo "Trunk local copy path: $TRUNK_PATH"

BRANCH_PATH=$(svn info --no-newline --show-item wc-root)
echo "Branch local copy path: $BRANCH_PATH"

SUBFOLDER=$(realpath --relative-to="$BRANCH_PATH" .)
echo "Comparing subfolders: $SUBFOLDER"

TRUNK_REVISION=$(svn mergeinfo --show-revs merged -R "$TRUNK_RELATIVE_URL" "$BRANCH_PATH" | tail -n 1)
if [[ -z "$TRUNK_REVISION" ]]; then
  TRUNK_REVISION=$(svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 --stop-on-copy -q | grep -oP "^r\K[0-9]+")
  echo "Comparison with trunk@$TRUNK_REVISION from which the current branch was copied"
else
  echo "Comparison with trunk@$TRUNK_REVISION with which the current branch was last merged"
fi

if [[ -d "$TRUNK_PATH/.svn" ]]; then
  echo "Found .svn subfolder in the local trunk copy, updating it"
  svn update -r $TRUNK_REVISION "$TRUNK_PATH"
else
  echo "Not found .svn subfolder in the local trunk copy, checking out it"
  svn checkout "$TRUNK_URL" -r $TRUNK_REVISION "$TRUNK_PATH"
fi

meld "$TRUNK_PATH/$SUBFOLDER" . &!
```

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

Question is offtopic here: as already mentioned in comment, it's question for Software Recommendations site

**Face**

1. *Every versioned object* with history in SVN can be referenced using [PEG-revision](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) for its history state
2. *Folder* in SVN-repo *is object* of versioning
3. In order to compare two folders, you have to have folder-diff tool (for your OS) and know (command-line) [options](https://meldmerge.org/help/command-line.html) for calling it

According to [Slant's comparison](https://www.slant.co/topics/5191/%7Esoftware-to-compare-2-folders-for-any-file-changes-and-highlight-them):

- Meld can be used on Linux for folder-diffing
- Best folder-diff tool is Beyond Compare

From points 1-3 above it follows that Meld can be used for your task in form

`meld folder@REV1 folder@REV2`

Comment: Seems that `meld` doesn't support `@REV1` syntax.

Comment: @Denis - you **can't** and **must not** use PEG-syntax out of scope of *pure SVN commands*. But you can integrate this command-line idea into `--diff-cmd` + `--extensions` options for `svn diff` or [helpers] section in ~/.subversion/config